# How to make hls/dash video for Flutter web

Tags: flutter, dart

I am using the plugin for video player -[plugin link](https://pub.dev/packages/video_player)

The same code is working for android, but not for web.

```
void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _controller = VideoPlayerController.network(
      
      'videourl.m3u8',
      formatHint: VideoFormat.hls,    
     
    );

    _controller.addListener(() {
      setState(() {});
    });
    _controller.setLooping(false);
    _controller.initialize();
}
```

The exact error I am getting is like this:

```
Uncaught (in promise) Error: PlatformException(MEDIA_ERR_SRC_NOT_SUPPORTED, No further diagnostic information can be determined or provided., The video has been found to be unsuitable (missing or in a format not supported by your browser)., null)
    

    at Object.createErrorWithStack (errors.dart:284)
    at Object._rethrow (async_patch.dart:200)
    at async._AsyncCallbackEntry.new.callback (zone.dart:1413)
    at Object._microtaskLoop (schedule_microtask.dart:40)
    at _startMicrotaskLoop (schedule_microtask.dart:49)
    at async_patch.dart:166
```

Do I need to add any additional info here to make it work for web?

Comment: Are you sure your .m3u8 contains a stream that uses a codec supported by the browser you're using?

Answer (score 1):

Please use **video_player_web_hls** package for hls video and
Add these line of code below  in index.html file in your flutter project directory,/web/index.html

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/hls.js@1"></script>
```

Comment: <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/hls.js@1"></script>